# Why is Drupal 7 not sending mails at all?

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7, smtp

This is my nightmare issue, I had it only twice in more than 30 sites and still am unable to resolve it. I tested everything I found, I read a huge amount of similar issues without any solution for me...

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists

Things I've tried so far :

1. Changing site **information > email details** to an email that contains the same domain name as the url (*ex:mail@domain.com*)

---

2. Configuring SMTP with drupal,

   ```
   1. turned module **on**
   2. turned delivery of mails **on**
   3. SMTP server : mail.infomaniak.ch
   4. SMTP Port : 25
   5. Encrypted protocol : TLS
   6. authentified with the correct credientials
   7. From : correctmail
   8. Debug True
   ```

> phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in PHPMailer->SmtpConnect(), SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

These errors comes on top of the default one with SMTP, my credentials are correct, I also turned **ON** **less secure apps to connect to my email** while I was using Gmail for SMTP.

The configuration of SMTP I use have to be like this since my host doesn't support SMTP in another way. You can see this [here](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/468/support-for-various-emailing-protocols).

---

3. I also tried to uninstall everything from my FTP & DB and I remigrated everything back with a newer version of drupal (7.56).

I'm loosing hope on this case, what would you suggest is there anything that could help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Try using different port 587?? https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/858/error-smtp-port-25-unrecognized-impossible-to-send-messages-from-an-email-client

Comment: First check if mail is working in your server end. Try something like mail in PHP just to check the mailer is working.